# Setting the variables in Makefile target not working as expected

Tags: variables, makefile, gnu-make

I have a simple Makefile where I would like to set a variable in one of the targets (so that I can use this variable in other targets).

My simple Makefile:

```
VAR=DEFAULT

import:
    echo $@
    VAR=$@
    echo $(VAR)
```

Output when I run "make import":

```
echo import
import
VAR=import
echo DEFAULT
DEFAULT
```

I was expecting VAR to be set to "import" but what's going on? Am I missing something here? Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

PS: Sorry if the question feels silly, tried googling a bit, don't have much time to do RnD! :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reassign the value to a variable which is already assigned with a value in the rules.
In your case: `VAR=$@` will not reassign the value `import` to the `VAR` as it is done inside the rules list. 
For this to work, you will have to do the same as part the dependency list, as below.

```
VAR=DEFAULT

#here VAR is assigned with the value import
import: VAR=$@ 
import:
    echo $@
    echo $(VAR)
```

Comment: it works in the given context, but I was not able to use the same variable in other targets of the makefile, I have a work-around for that. Thanks anyway! :)